# MongoDB Aggregation Query - rename nested of nested field's name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm doing data lineage thing to trace the reference of data so my result will be nested too deep and I tried to `$lookup` `$unwind` `$project` and `$group` to get this result but i cant find the way to rename a field deep inside and it doesn't work.

Result from aggregation:

```
{
  childrens: {
      childrens: [{
          childrens: [{
            childrens: [
            { title: 'test table'},
            { title: 'testMetric'},
            { title: 'testPothai'}
            ]
          },{...}]
      }]
  }
},{
  childrens: {
      childrens: [{
          childrens: [{
            childrens: [
            { title: 'test table2'},
            { title: 'testPothai2'}
            ]
          },{...}]
      }]
  }
},
```

I want to change `title` field to `name` and remove `children` field in case it's empty.

Could you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mongo isn't useful for very deep nested documents, and less useful if you post such a general structure.

Comment: Hi @Minsky do you mean my data is not complex or i do anything wrong?

Comment: Do u need to update the documents? Im bit confused, you mentioned "Aggregation"

Comment: You can update using aggregation @varman. I'm just saying it won't be easy, and it's normally not recommended to have unbounded arrays (I assume they are), or deeply nested structures.

Comment: Do you talk about `$out` ?

Comment: No. `update` now allows using a pipeline (4.2+). But $out could work too.

Comment: @varman These collection came from aggression my bad i describe it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by `$map` in `$project` before `$group`, Finding the new way to reduce stage.